# SimpleDateFormatter with Timezone

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to parse the following Dateformat

> 26.04.2015 17:00 CET

I used the following pattern String

> dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z

I am using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. But when I try to parse the given String I receive a `ParseException`.

I am using the following code

```
String datestring = "26.04.2015 17:00 CET";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z");
Date dt = format.parse(datestring)
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please Show the Code what you have written

Comment: I added the Code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Benjy Kessler is okay (my upvote). The symbol z is for parsing timezone names and abbreviations, the symbol Z for parsing offsets.

The only point which is still missing is the locale. You have to set the locale to English because "CET" is an English abbreviation for "Central European Time". In German it would be "MEZ" instead.

So please try the expression

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

By the way, your input seems to be inconsistent because your date is in April but "CET" suggests winter time (while the European Union EU already has switched to summer time). I hope your format-object is lenient enough.

Comment: I already played around with capital and lower z. the main thing I was missing, is to pass the Locale.ENGLISH. I tried to pass the value MEZ (I am running a german PC) and it worked fine. So I think I would never run into the problem, when I would live in the UK or US :) Thanks for your help and the hint with summer time (CEST)

Comment: @MichaelMeyer Glad to help you. I am living in Germany, too, so I am probably more sensitive for localization than many native English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Use lowercase `z` instead of capital `Z`.

You will have `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("26.04.2015 17:00 CET", new ParsePosition(0)));
```

> Sun Apr 26 12:00:00 EDT 2015

You can see a demo [here](http://goo.gl/VeD7li).

You can see a full description of parameters for `SimpleDateFormat` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: sorry, but the result stays the same. I still receive the parse exception

Answer (score 0):

Try `SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: and how to pass the timezone information?

Comment: As Meno Hochschild stated in his answer.